Continuity of functionals on $\mathbb R^{\mathbb N}$
In this question on MO I asked why people would not use $\mathbb R^{\mathbb N}$ (that is, the Cartesian product of countably many copies of $\mathbb R$) endowed with the topology of pointwise convergence to model high-dimensionality. A sequence in $\mathbb R^{\mathbb N}$ converges in this topology to a limit if and only if the sequence of coordinates converges to the  corresponding coordiante of the limit. As pointed out in the comments of the answer to my question, the problem with this space (resp. this topology) is that many 'interesting' functionals (i.e., real-valued functions on $\mathbb R^{\mathbb N}$) are not continuous. One example given is $$f(y) = \sup_{p\in\mathbb N}\frac{y(p)}{a(p)}$$ for some positive sequence $a$ (i.e., $a(p)>0$ for all $p\in\mathbb N$). For simplicity, let's take $a \equiv 1$, and consider the sequence $(y_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ in $\mathbb R^{\mathbb N}$ with $$y_n(p) = 1 - \left(\frac{n}{1+n}\right)^p.$$ Clearly, $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}y_n(p) = 0$ for all $p\in\mathbb N$, and hence $f(\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}y_n) = 0$. On the other hand, since $$f(y_n) = \sup_{p\in\mathbb N}\left(1 - \left(\frac{n}{1+n}\right)^p\right) = 1$$ for all $n\in\mathbb N$, we have that $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}f(y_n) = 1$. That is, $$1 = \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}f(y_n) \neq f(\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}y_n) = 0,$$ i.e., $f$ is not (sequential) continuous. Q1: Is this argument correct?
Let's now turn our attention to the functional $$g(y) = \sum_{p=1}^\infty \vert y(p)\vert.$$
Consider the sequence $(y_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ in $\mathbb R^{\mathbb N}$ with $$y_n(p) = \frac 1{np}.$$ Clearly, $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}y_n = 0$ for all $p\in\mathbb N$, and hence $g(\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}y_n) = 0$. On the other hand, $$g(y_n) = \sum_{p=1}^\infty\frac 1{np} = \infty$$ for all $n\in\mathbb N$, and therefore $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}g(y_n) = \infty$. That is, $$\infty = \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}g(y_n) \neq g(\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}y_n) = 0,$$ i.e., $g$ is not (sequential) continuous. Q2: Is this argument correct?
By slightly tweaking the sequence in the latter case, the argument (assuming it is correct) generalizes easily to all $\ell^p$-norms, while the former case proves failure of continuity of the $\ell^\infty$-norm. Q3: are there any 'interesting' functionals on all of $\mathbb R^{\mathbb N}$? Clearly, there are some trivial examples like a constant function, but I could not think of more yet.

How would you go about generating a distance function on that space?

I think this is the standard metric/distance used on this space: $d(x,y) = \sum_{p=1}^\infty 2^{-p}\frac{\vert x(p) - y(p)\vert}{1+ \vert x(p) - y(p)\vert}$. This metric metrizes the topology of pointwise convergence
